# Creating a relationship between a document and a collection in MongoDB

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, nosql

I have no idea if this is even possible but I'd like to find out if there's some way to create a relationship between a document and a whole collection. I have a `user` schema that looks something like this:

```
var userSchema = new Schema({
    fname: {type: String, required: true},
    lname: {type: String, required: true},
    email: {type: String, required: true, unique: true},
    password: {type:String, required: true}
});
```

To achieve my desired goal, I'm thinking my schema would need to look a bit like this:

```
var userSchema = new Schema({
    fname: {type: String, required: true},
    lname: {type: String, required: true},
    email: {type: String, required: true, unique: true},
    password: {type:String, required: true},
    collections: [{type: Schema.Types.ObjectId}] // where ObjectId would be the ID to a collection

});
```

The problem with this approach is, I have no way to get the ID of a collection. I'm unsure if that's even a thing. Any suggestions? Is this even possible?

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Please share database

Comment: ids are get generated with document not collection.

Answer (score 0):

The idea behind using schema is to create a sense of an object-relational database model. This article helps to explain how this is achieved: [Data Modeling Guidelines for NoSQL JSON Document Databases](https://mapr.com/blog/data-modeling-guidelines-nosql-json-document-databases/).

When using NoSQL databases I used [MongooseJS](https://mongoosejs.com). I would want to believe it is simple and easy to use.

I hope this helps.